# PHP Offsetting unix timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

I have a unix timestamp in `PHP`:

```
$timestamp = 1346300336;
```

Then I have an offset for timezones which I want to apply. Basically, I want to apply the offset and return a new unix timestamp. The offset follows this format, and unfortunately can't be changed due to compatibility with other code:

```
$offset_example_1 = "-07:00";
$offset_example_2 = "+00:00";
$offset_example_3 = "+07:00";
```

I tried:

```
$new_timestamp = strtotime($timestamp . " " . $offset_example_1);
```

But this does **not** work unfortunately :(. Any other ideas?

**EDIT**

After testing, I super surprised, but even this doesn't work:

```
strtotime("1346300336 -7 hours")
```

Returns false.

Let's approach this a bit different, what is the best way to transform the offset examples above, into seconds? Then I can simply just do `$timestamp + $timezone_offset_seconds`.

Answer (score 6):

You should pass the original timestamp as the second parameter to `strtotime`.

```
$new_timestamp = strtotime("-7 hours", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Are you sure `strtotime("-07:00", 1346300336)` works? I am getting back the original `1346300336`.

Comment: @Justin Oh, it returns `1346357936`.

Comment: I am getting the same result back `1346300336` when trying `strtotime("-07:00", 1346300336)`

Comment: @Justin it should be like this `strtotime("-7 hours", 1346300336)`. You have missed the word **hours**

Answer (score 1):

```
 $dt = new DateTime();
 $dt->setTimezone('GMT'); //Or whatever
 $dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
 $dt->setTimezone('Pacific');
 //Echo out/do whatever
 $dt->setTimezone('GMT');
```

I like the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) Class a lot.

Comment: I don't have timezones stored in the format of `GMT` or `Pacific`, I store the offset, as shown above.

Comment: Might not be ideal but you could make an array to map timezones to offsets

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateInterval:

```
$t = 1346300336;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d', $t));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('-7 hours'); 
$date->add($interval);

echo $date->getTimestamp();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```