# PHP Time to Javascript Clock

Tags: javascript, php, time, timezone, clock

I want to simply just pull the time from the server.
And continue it ticking with javascript.

My PHP.

```
//Get current UNIX timestamp (no offset, just straight timestamp)
$time = time()*1000;

//Get offset of server time
$offset = date('O');

// Convert into a new timestamp based on the timezone
$newtime = $time+$offset;

// a vardump($newtime) here gives me
// 1415169764400
```

My Javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Here Im putting the server time into a variable
var serverTime = "<?php echo $newtime;?>"; 
//console.log(serverTime) gives me 1415169764400

// Local computer time into a variable
var localTime = new Date().getTime(); 
//console.log(localTime) here gives me 1415170692954

// Offset between the computer and the server
var timeDiff = serverTime - localTime; 
// console.log(timeDiff) here gives me -928554  

//The ticking clock function
setInterval(function () {
    // Set clock to Computer time plus the time difference
    var today = new Date(Date.now()+timeDiff);
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m); //checktime() is just a leading zero function
    s = checkTime(s); // checktime() is just a leading zero function
    var formatted = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    $('.serverTime').html(formatted);
}, 2000);
//PROBLEM IS THAT THIS DISPLAYS THE CURRENT TIME ON MY COMPUTER
// NO MATTER WHAT I TRY, IT ALWAYS JUST DISPLAYS THE LOCAL TIME
// No matter what PHP timezone I put.
// The time Diff and server times are working properly.
// Any ideas whats happening!!???
});
```

I normally would just use the users local computer time, but each server is in a different location, and when they are visiting this page, I want the clock to tick to the server they're currently visiting.

Comment: $newtime = strtotime($offset, $time);
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190510/php-offsetting-unix-timestamp

Comment: doing that just made mu javascript date jump to 2037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$time` is the number of seconds since unix epoch, expressed as **milliseconds**.  `$offset` is the number of **hours** difference from GMT*, Eg `'-0800'`.  Your first problem is that you are adding the offset to the timestamp.  At most, you are changing the time by 1.4 seconds, where you seem to intend to change the time by hours.

It would be much easier if you use a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object instead.  Then you can call `.getOffset()` which gives you the difference in seconds:

```
<?php 
$date = new DateTime();

// Get offset for UNIX timestamp based on server timezone
$time = $date->getTimestamp();

//Get offset of server time
$offset = $date->getOffset();

// Convert into a new timestamp based on the timezone
$newtime = ($time + $offset) * 1000;
?>
```

So far, we've been dealing only with UTC dates.  Your other problem is that you are using the local date methods to get values out.  You should use the UTC versions of these methods.

```
//Actual ticking clock
setInterval(function () {
    var today = new Date(Date.now() + timeDiff);
    var h=today.getUTCHours();
    var m=today.getUTCMinutes();
    var s=today.getUTCSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    var formatted = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    $('.serverTime').html(formatted);
}, 2000);
```

Here's the whole thing, with simulated server time:

```js
function simulateServerTime() {
    var time = new Date();
    // Add 1 minute and 12 seconds to simulate the clocks being a little out of sync
    time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + 1, 12);
    // Reduce to seconds to simulate php
    time = Math.round(time / 1000);
    // Specify an offset of -6 hours
    var offset = -6 * 60 * 60;
    return (time + offset) * 1000;
}

var serverTime = simulateServerTime();

var localTime = new Date();

// Offset between the computer and the server
var timeDiff = serverTime - localTime;

// The ticking clock function
setInterval(function () {
  var today = new Date(Date.now() + timeDiff);
  var h=today.getUTCHours();
  var m=today.getUTCMinutes();
  var s=today.getUTCSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  var formatted = h+":"+m+":"+s;
  document.querySelector(".serverTime").innerHTML = formatted;
}, 1000);

// Helper function for leading 0's
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

```html
<div class="serverTime"></div>
```

---

*Or, [so says the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).  Last week, my machine said -0700, which is the octal representation of -448.  My time is neither 700 hours earlier than GMT, nor is it 448 hours earlier than GMT, it's 7 hours earlier.  It annoys me that the documentation states that it is the time offset in hours, when really it's the [time offset in ISO 8601 Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC).

Comment: This almost worked.  At least id din't just show me my local time.  It was 14:15 here, and this displayed 22:15.  So somethings working.  But its the wrong offset.  Since it should've been displaying 16:15. (2 hours ahead)  My PHP timezone is set to America/Chicago and Im in America/Los_Angeles zone

Comment: @KyleK - Add this to your code: `console.log("Server offset: <?php echo $offset;?>")`  Central time (UTC-0600) should give `-21600`.  Sounds like you are getting `0` back for the offset.

Comment: Added that, and I am getting -21600

Comment: @KyleK - I don't know.  I added a full working demo to my answer.  I had to simulate the server, but it should work.  If you are still seeing UTC displayed in the browser, that makes me think that `timeDiff` isn't being added to the date, or `timeDiff` somehow got set to `0`.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyways.....Im gonna accept your answer because techinically it is correct.  Just didn't fix my problem.  I gave up anyways....and am just gonna diplay the static server time now.  I couldn't be bothered to waste hours on something so trivial...lol

Comment: Real server time? For anyone who wants to display real server time with php, just change: `var serverTime = <?php echo(time() * 1000); ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp is not include timezone offset. Everyone's unix time is a offset from Jan 1, 1970 in UTC

If you wish to display a server timezone in client, your PHP must provide a server timezone. And about client timezone, you can reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript) .

Also, I like to using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to handle date/time problems.

---

I just modified the client side javascript, using moment. Wish it's all you needed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens");

$serverTime =  time() * 1000 ;
$timezone = date('O');

?>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
  var serverTime = <?php echo $serverTime;?>,
    timezone = "<?php echo $timezone;?>",
    timeDiff = serverTime - Date.now();

  setInterval(function () {
      result.innerHTML= moment().add(timeDiff).zone(timezone).format('HH:mm:ss Z') + "<br/>" + result.innerHTML  ;
  }, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: Im providing the server timezone offset with date('O') its reading my timezone from the database and outputting the correct offset

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP. But your `$offset = date('O');` will returns a string. And PHP seems will not concatenate integer and string. But try to parse string and generate results. Like if your timezone is Denver `'-0700'` and timestamp is `1415175975300` it will result `1415175974600`. So your new time was incorrect. You maybe need to use `$offset = date('Z')*1000;` .